# spring + data-jpa org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

i'm trying to build an app mvc with spring security and persistence(jpa) and i'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'recipeDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 85 more
```

The problem seems to be that the entity manager factory isn't able to create the proxy bean needed. This is my xml context param:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:rep="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jlab.recipesspringmvc"/>
<rep:repositories base-package="com.jlab.recipesspringmvc.dao"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!-- MVC -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean id="validator" class="com.jlab.recipesspringmvc.utils.RecipeValidator"/>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="validation"/>
</bean>
<!-- Hibernate -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor "/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recipesspringmvc" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jlab.recipesspringmvc.bean" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!-- fix per il problema del lazy-init sulle collections -->
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<!--Security -->
<!-- Abilitiamo le annotazioni di security per il Service Layer: deve trovarsi nel file del component-scan -->
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/create" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/delete" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/update" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern='/review' access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <sec:form-login 
        login-page="/index" 
        login-processing-url="/indexLogin" 
        default-target-url="/index" 
        authentication-failure-url="/index?error=true"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
</sec:http>  

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.jlab.recipesspringmvc.utils.LoginCast" />

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="256"/>
</bean>    
</beans>
```

The class that tries to @Autowire the incriminated Dao

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CreateImpl implements Create{
    @Autowired
    private RecipeDao recipeDao;
    @Autowired
    private CategoryDao categoryDao;
    @Autowired
    private ReportedRecipeDao repDao;
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;
//implementation
}
```

the Dao extending CrudRepository

```
@Repository
public interface RecipeDao extends CrudRepository<Recipe, Long> {

    public List<Recipe> findByName(String name);
    public Recipe findById(Long id);
    public List<Recipe> findByUser(User user);

}
```

and last but not the least, my Pom

```html
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.sec.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.sec.version>
        <spring.data.version>1.11.4.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <!--  <tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version> -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.sec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.sec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.sec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.sec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I've tried to search for answers to my problem since like 3 days ago. Help me please, you guys are my last resort, sorry to bother.

Comment: if you comment `recipeDao` the others dao throws the same output

Comment: Can you try declaring the recipeDao in the applicationContext.xml?

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat sure, i could, but it's an interface and it has no "real" implementation, spring data jpa should create a proxy implementation for it. I tried and this is the result (as expected)
{Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.jlab.recipesspringmvc.dao.RecipeDao]: Specified class is an interface}

Comment: @JorgeL.Morla yup, sorry, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to answer myself, I solved it deleting the

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

dependency. Probably there was some problem with the versioning or conflict.